# Typescript linter: reference to external library

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, bokeh, bokehjs

I want to write a custom component for Bokeh, that means that I have to edit a TypeScript file that is somewhat "disconnected" from its environment. My question is how to make linting work properly.

Namely I have a file "component.ts" with header:

```
import * as p from "core/properties"
import {div, input} from "core/dom"
import {InputWidget, InputWidgetView} from "models/widgets/input_widget"
```

The file is buried deep in a python project directory. Compiling everything is bokeh's responsibility and it does it from its Python interface. But I know where those includes are located in my disk. Can I make my IDE nicer so it knows how to search that stuff without all those red underlines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to `tsconfig.json` these lines:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "paths" : {
            "core/*": ["/path/to/core/*"],
            "models/*": ["/path/to/models/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["path/to/component.ts"],
    ...
}
```